# How do I use scrapy to scrape data between a start point and an end point on a webpage

Tags: scrapy

I am working on an interest project in which I use a list of drug names to find the side effects of cancer treatment drugs. I want to store the side effects that occur in greater than 30% of the cases. I am a complete newbie to scrapy (I have been using it for about 3 days). So I am on this webpage http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/camptosar.aspx, and I am trying to get the data that appears between the sentences:

"The following side effects are common (occurring in greater than 30%) for patients taking Camptosar" 
and 
"These side effects are less common side effects (occurring in about 10-29%) of patients receiving Camptosar".

The data that I am looking for does not seem to be in a uniquely identified piece of html, it is just simply multiple lists, so I cannot just say look at this section and take data from this section. Googling did not come up with any results that I found helpful.

Is there a way to do this in scrapy? All the drugs I wish to get side effects for have their side effects listed between those two strings on each page. Some more of the pages I am trying to scrape from in case its needed http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/avastin.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get all the elements in between the two paragraphs using the *Kayessian method* set intersection, :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

# expressions to find the two p tags we want.
ns1 = "//p[contains(. , '(occurring in greater than 30%)')]"
ns2 = "//p[contains(., '(occurring in about 10-29%)')]"

tree = html.fromstring(requests.get("http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/camptosar.aspx").content)

x = """ {ns1}/following-sibling::*
        [count(. | {ns2}/preceding-sibling::*)
        =
         count({ns2}/preceding-sibling::*)
        ]
        """.format(ns1=ns1, ns2=ns2)

print(tree.xpath(x))
```

Which would output:

```
[<Element ul at 0x7f0c39edc998>, <Element blockquote at 0x7f0c39edc9f0>, <Element ul at 0x7f0c39edca48>, <Element strong at 0x7f0c39edcaa0>, <Element blockquote at 0x7f0c39edcaf8>, <Element ul at 0x7f0c39edcb50>]
```

If you just wanted the ul's you would remove the * and replace them with `ul`:

```
x = """ {ns1}/following-sibling::ul
        [count(. | {ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul)
        =
         count({ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul)
        ]
        """.format(ns1=ns1, ns2=ns2)
```

Which would then give you:

```
[<Element ul at 0x7fe3e8ac0aa0>, <Element ul at 0x7fe3e8ac0af8>, <Element ul at 0x7fe3e8ac0b50>]
```

So to get the links and the side-effects we could use `ul/li/a`:

```
In [12]: x = """ {ns1}/following-sibling::ul/li/a
   ....:         [count(. | {ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul/li/a)
   ....:         =
   ....:          count({ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul/li/a)
   ....:         ]
   ....:         """.format(ns1=ns1, ns2=ns2)

In [13]: for a in tree.xpath(x):
   ....:         print(a.text, a.xpath("@href"))
   ....:     
('Diarrhea', ['../side-effects/diarrhea-and-chemotherapy.aspx'])
('Nausea and vomiting', ['../side-effects/nausea-vomiting-chemotherapy.aspx'])
('Weakness', ['../side-effects/weakness.aspx'])
('Low white blood\r\n            cell count', ['../side-effects/low-blood-counts.aspx#LowWhite'])
('Low red blood cell\r\n            count', ['../side-effects/low-blood-counts.aspx#LowRed'])
('Hair loss', ['../side-effects/hair-loss-and-chemotherapy.aspx'])
('Poor appetite', ['../side-effects/cancer-and-chemobased-lack-of.aspx'])
('Fever', ['../side-effects/fever-neutropenic-fever-and-their-relationship-to-chemotherapy.aspx'])
('Weight loss', ['../side-effects/weight-changes.aspx'])
```

Which you can see exactly matches the page:

[image]
A working spider example:

```
class DrugsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "drug_spider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/camptosar.aspx",
                  "http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/Eloxatin.aspx"]

    ns1 = "//p[contains(. , '(occurring in greater than 30%)')]"
    ns2 = "//p[contains(., '10-29%)')]"

    x = """ {ns1}/following-sibling::ul/li
            [count(. | {ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul/li)
            =
             count({ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul/li)
            ]
            """.format(ns1=ns1, ns2=ns2)

    def parse(self, response):
        for li in response.xpath(self.x):
            print(li.xpath("normalize-space(.)").extract())


from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

p = CrawlerProcess()
p.crawl(DrugsSpider)
p.start()
```

Output:

```
2016-09-22 22:43:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/Eloxatin.aspx> (referer: None)
[u'Numbness and tingling (peripheral neuropathy) and cramping of the hands or feet often triggered by cold.\xa0\xa0 This symptom will generally lessen or go away between treatments, however as the number of treatments increase the numbness and tingling will take longer to lessen or go away.\xa0 Your health care professional will monitor this symptom with you and adjust your dose accordingly.']
[u'Nausea and vomiting']
[u'Diarrhea']
[u'Mouth sores\xa0']
[u'Low blood counts.\xa0 Your white and red blood cells and platelets may temporarily decrease.\xa0 This can put you at increased risk for infection, anemia and/or bleeding.']
[u'Fatigue']
[u'Loss of appetite']
2016-09-22 22:43:28 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/camptosar.aspx> (referer: None)
[u'Diarrhea - two types:']
[u'Nausea and vomiting']
[u'Weakness']
[u'Low white blood cell count (this can put you at increased risk for infection)']
[u'Low red blood cell count (anemia)']
[u'Hair loss']
[u'Poor appetite']
[u'Fever']
[u'Weight loss']
2016-09-22 22:43:28 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect and exactly what I wanted to know about. I was wondering if you could help me combine this with scrapy? Specifically this line : tree = html.fromstring(requests.get("http://www.chemocare.com/chemotherapy/drug-info/Eloxatin.aspx").content). Creates a response object correct? Scrapy also has a response object, is there anyway to use scrapy's response with lxml?

Comment: @AjayBhullar., you use the xpath exactly the same in scrapy. There is no difference. Actually `response.xpath` in scrapy uses lxml

Comment: I guess my question really is, in the parse method I don't know how to get the url of the page it is currently parsing, so I can't pass it into the requests.get(), Are you saying that I can simply ignore this step and use the response.body of scrapy?

Comment: You just call `response.xpath(the_xpath)`, also you can probable change ns2 to  `ns2 = "//p[contains(., '10-29%)')]"` to work for both variations

Comment: Okay I think I figured it all out, you are right I can just skip the html.requests.get part and use the response directly, in case anyone was wondering. Thank you so much man

Comment: @AjayBhullar., I added a working spider so it should be pretty clear now.

Comment: Okay perfect I have everything working now, thank you so much for your help. My final question is could you explain whats happening here:  x = """ {ns1}/following-sibling::ul/li
            [count(. | {ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul/li)
            =
             count({ns2}/preceding-sibling::ul/li)
            ]
            """.format(ns1=ns1, ns2=ns2) or if you could provide a link to documentation on it or something that would be great. I feel like I understand that it sets the intersection but I would not be able to reproduce this later with my current understanding.